# SQL Query to get the last unique value from a column

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table with the following columns:

id | created_at

I want to get a dictionary of all the unique id's and the latest created_at time.

My current query is this:

```
SELECT id, created_at from uscis_case_history
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This gives me the latest id, but i want one for all unique id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to aggregate:

```
SELECT id, MAX(created_at) LatestCreated_at
FROM uscis_case_history
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY MAX(created_at) DESC;
```

Comment: Of course it is this simple, I wonder why my mind went to `row_number`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number` to index the dates based on their id and then filter by that:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT id,
               created_at,
               row_number() over (partition by id order by created_at desc) rn
          FROM tbl) a
 WHERE rn=1
```

Here is an [example on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pfzyckhvqkVMsHXqLmWgV1/0)